# Unable to load jri.dll while trying to run R from Java(IntelliJ)

Tags: java, r, intellij-idea

I am trying to call jri.dll from java

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("jri");
}
```

I've also set library path in VM options:

```
-Djava.library.path="D:\rJava\jri\x64;C:\Program Files\R\R-3.5.1\bin\x64;"
```

Cannot find JRI native library!
Please make sure that the JRI native library is in a directory listed in java.library.path.

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: D:\rJava\jri\x64\jri.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1941)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1857)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
at org.rosuda.JRI.Rengine.<clinit>(Rengine.java:19)
```

Comment: Did you tried to load with complete path of jri.dll?

Comment: What libraries does `jri.dll` depend on? You can use http://www.dependencywalker.com/ to find out. Are they all available in `PATH` or in `java.library.path` and are they all of the same architecture (x64)?

Comment: @Spara, I gave complete path in VM options and I'm trying to loadLibrary jri.dll into it

Comment: @CrazyCoder Thanks I'll check for the dependent libraries.

Comment: But it is helpless